# Are these all possible mobile devices resolutions?

Tags: unity, mobile, resolution

In `Unity`, there's a switch where you can set your desired resolution and check if the game looks ok:

[image]

If I target the app for portait only - do I have to worry only about these here, marked as 'portrait', or list the possible aspect ratios from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are 5 common aspect ratio types:

- 4:3 (Probably only the IPad)
- 3:2 (Iphone 1-4, it's getting obsolete)
- 5:3 (This is getting obsolete)
- 16:10 (Mostly tablets)
- 16:9 (Iphone 5-7 and newer android phones)

Some of the options in unity are "duplicates", for instance the 320*480 resolution is just a 2:3 resolution

Comment: So this means, that If I add these ratios (by default in Unity there are only landscapes - 16:9, 5:3 etc.) and check them - the app will be fine on all possible devices, right?

Comment: @Spectre if you check on only 2, then the program will be fine on any, but yeah.